# How i can use RecyclerView inside a fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

i try to implement recyclerView inside a fragment. When i try to open my app it crashes. i have a BottomNavigationMenu and i want to implement recyclerView inside one of the fragments. here is my code:

HomeFragment.kt

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*


private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

private var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager? = null
private var adapter: 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder>? = null


class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
arguments?.let {
}
layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
recycler.layoutManager = layoutManager
adapter = RecyclerAdapter()
recycler.adapter = adapter
}

override fun onCreateView(
inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
}

companion object {
@JvmStatic
fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
    HomeFragment().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
            putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
        }
    }
}
}
```

how i can implement it correctly

Comment: Can you include the crash info?

Comment: @danartillaga when i open my app on emulator it just closes, there is no error with code itself. I think it might be because i need to access my recycler view in onViewCreated() but idk how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your calls to your `RecyclerView` from `onCreate` to `onViewCreated`

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
    recycler.layoutManager = layoutManager
    adapter = RecyclerAdapter()
    recycler.adapter = adapter
}
```

Comment: yep it works thanks!